# Synchronous pymol

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, pymol

I am trying to load an mrc file, generate the map of it and then save the image, the problem is that it only saves a blank image, the code I run is the following:

```
from pymol import cmd
cmd.load('./6vof.mrc', ' 6vof')
cmd.volume( '6vof _volume', ' 6vof')
cmd.png('./test.png', 300, 200)
```

The equivalent code in the interface does work, I wanted to know how I can make the save method wait for the rendering of everything.

Comment: I don't know very much about PyMOL, but I wonder if the spaces within the quotes of the `cmd.load()` and `cmd.volume()` lines are part of the issue or if this is just the normal format. Does anything change if you remove the spaces so that line 2 looks like this: `cmd.load('./6vof.mrc', '6vof')` and line 3 looks like this: `cmd.volume('6vof_volume', '6vof')` ?

Comment: Hello, let's not say the problem is not that it does not work but that the image storage is executed first before the volume has been completely generated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Luis José Castillo,

it seems I encountered the same problem as you did.
I wanted to use Pymol from within a Ruby on Rails application and always got his message, when I launched it from within ruby:

```
 CmdLoad: "mypol/4hhb.pdb" loaded as "4hhb".
 Ray: render time: 0.02 sec. = 178776.9 frames/hour (0.02 sec. accum.).
```

The result was a blank transparent png. If I ran it in the command line with the same script I got this message and a perfect png:

```
CmdLoad: "4hhb.pdb" loaded as "4hhb".
 Ray: render time: 4.04 sec. = 890.8 frames/hour (4.04 sec. accum.).
```

I got this behavoir on Ubuntu 20, Ubuntu 18 Server and in Docker.
I figured out, that the only difference was, I used relative paths from within ruby, but was always running everything in the same folder in the command line.
Well, so I just make this detour for my Rails application and now it does work:

```
  def get_protein_image(pdb_id)
    dir_path = get_pdb_file(pdb_id)
    `cp lib/png_from_pdb.py #{dir_path} && cd #{dir_path} && pymol protein.pdb png_from_pdb.py -qc` 
  end
```

Sorry for the ruby code here, but here the essential solution, try to run everything inside the same folder (I simply delete the tmp subfolder after png generation).

```
cp lib/png_from_pdb.py #{dir_path} && cd #{dir_path} && pymol protein.pdb png_from_pdb.py -qc
```

I hope this trick will help you too!
Best regards,
Stephan

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement what you told me but the storage execution keeps happening before :cccc, that is, it did not work for me.